# Implementing Material Design Theme in Android using Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I'm using Delphi XE8 for developing Android mobile application. And I need to implement Material View title bar in my application. And how can I able to implement using Delphi XE8? [Material view Example.](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) Please provide me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add to form StyleBook, doubleclick and load Adroid's style.

Comment: Where can I get this style?

Comment: Can you please provide me any example